# Integrating Facebook php SDK in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, facebook

I am trying to integrate facebook api in laravel. 
I had update my composer.

I am stuck with the error :

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException thrown with
>   message "Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine::main(): Failed opening
>   required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\mero-theatre-sm-integration\storage\framework\viewsfb/fb/src/Facebook/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')"

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once __DIR__ .'fb/fb/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '369611640182768',
  'app_secret' => '909...................',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.12',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email']; // optional

try {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
    } else {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }
} catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

    exit;
} catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    } else {
        // getting short-lived access token
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

        // OAuth 2.0 client handler
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;

        // setting default access token to be used in script
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }

    // redirect the user back to the same page if it has "code" GET variable
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        header('Location: ./');
    }

    // getting basic info about user
    try {
        $profile_request = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email');
        $profile = $profile_request->getGraphNode()->asArray();
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        session_destroy();
        // redirecting user back to app login page
        header("Location: ./");
        exit;
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    // printing $profile array on the screen which holds the basic info about user
    print_r($profile);

// Now you can redirect to another page and use the access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
} else {
    // replace your website URL same as added in the developers.facebook.com/apps e.g. if you used http instead of https and you used non-www version or www version of your website then you must add the same here
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://sohaibilyas.com/fbapp/', $permissions);
    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
}
```

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945596/how-to-integrate-facebook-php-sdk-with-laravel-5-4

Comment: After enter the credentials in .env file when i tried to update my composer i got                                                                                          **Key require is a duplicate in ./composer.json ** this error

Comment: what does your folder sturcture look like?