# How to get path in app.php provider and aliases after install a composer package in Laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php

In laravel , I do

```
composer require facebook/graph-sdk
```

and it's done,
but how to register this package in laravel project after this?

I know i have to go to app.php and change

```
'providers' => [...
```

and

```
'aliases' => [....
```

but how do I know what to append?
How can I get it when I install other packages?

I hope I can  do

```
use Facebook;
```

in the controller, but I don't know how to.

Comment: As mentioned in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945596/how-to-integrate-facebook-php-sdk-with-laravel-5-4 you can manually register Facebook sdk.

Comment: @J.Doe That’s a complete lie, given I’ve done so in multiple Laravel applications in the past, and have just posted an answer with an example of how to do exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

The Facebook Graph SDK is just a generic PHP SDK. You’ll want to create a service provider in your Laravel application that binds its configuration values.

First, create environment variables named `FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID` and `FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET`.

Next, bind those environment variables to configuration values. Open your **config/services.php** file and add the following:

```php
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
],
```

Now, use Artisan to create a service provider (`php artisan make:provider FacebookServiceProvider`) and add it to the `providers` array in **config/app.php**.

The service provider should look like this:

```php
use Facebook\Facebook;

class FacebookServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = true;

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(Facebook::class, function ($app) {
            return new Facebook([
                'app_id' => $app['config']['services.facebook.client_id'],
                'app_secret' => $app['config']['services.facebook.client_secret'],
                'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
            ]);
        });
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return [
            Facebook::class,
        ];
    }
}
```

This adds a *configured* instance of the Facebook Graph SDK to your application’s container, meaning you can type-hint it in your classes’ constructors and use it:

```php
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    private $facebook;

    public function __construct(Facebook $facebook)
    {
        $this->facebook = $facebook;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        // Can use $this->facebook and it’ll already be
        // configured with app ID and secret.
    }
}
```

The service provider is also deferred, meaning the SDK is only loaded when you request it.

Comment: thanks , but what if i wanna require other packages?

Comment: @黃皓哲 Then require other packages.

Comment: i mean , how do i know what to append in app.php? or just see the document of the package?

Comment: @黃皓哲 It depends if it’s a Laravel package or just a generic PHP package.